# How to change Java's default installation folder for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, linux

I have my .minecraft folder on a USB drive, but it's getting old to keep copying and pasting it into my root directory every time I want to play. It's nice keeping all my Minecraft files on a USB, but I would like to be able to run the entire game from the USB. It seems that Java always looks on my PC's program/app data files even if I run the Minecraft launcher from the USB. Is there a way to change Java's default root directory to a USB?

I am using a Linux Mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out symbolic links. I use them to keep my saves linked between my linux and windows partitions. Basically, you make the `.minecraft` folder on your system's drive link to the `.minecraft` folder on your USB drive.

```
ln -s /your/usb/drive/.minecraft /your/hard/drive/.minecraft
```

To force overwrite the destination folder, use `-sf` instead of `-s`

I don't know if there's actually a way to change the minecraft installation directory, but this should provide a good workaround.